# confusion why interface has been inherited again when the base interface already inherits it

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I was reviewing inheritance and had some confusion about inheriting an interface. Let's take for example `List<T>`.

I have this basic declaration:

```
List<string> categoryList = new List<string>();
```

When I click `Go to Definition` while the cursor is on `List`, it shows me this code,

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IList, ICollection, 
                       IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, 
                       IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{

}
```

If I click `Go to Definition` again while the cursor is on `IList<T>`

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{

}
```

Now my question is: Why does `List<T>` is still inheriting `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable` when `IList<T>` already inherits it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is just the way Visual Studio represents definitions, it shows you the whole interface hierarchy.

If you view the [Reference Source for List<T>](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#33), you will see it only implements *IList<T>*, *System.Collections.IList*, and *IReadOnlyList<T>*, as implementing *IEnumerable<T>* would be redundant.

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, System.Collections.IList, IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    // bla bla bla
}
```

Comment: +1 for that if you see `ICollection` interface it is again inherited by `IEnumarable`.

Answer (score 3):

**It's clearly for readability purposes**. The code would compile just fine with only three interfaces specified:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, IList, IReadOnlyList<T>
{

}
```

But this way, you have to know, that `IList` inherits `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`, and `IList<T>` implements `ICollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`, and that `IReadOnlyList<T>` inherits `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.